# Simple steady-state advection problem: do I need FVM with upwind scheme?

Tags: finite-volume, advection

I have a 2D (x,y) scalar advection problem that describes net blowing snow ($q$) transport at a point. This takes the form

$$q = A - F*\nabla\cdot(q {\bf \hat u}),$$

where A ($kg\cdot m^{-2}\cdot s^{-1}$) is a spatially variable scalar source term, $F$ is fetch (m) and $\hat u$ unit normal parallel to to the wind direction (unitless); $\hat u$ is spatially variable. Initial conditions are [ I believe] $q(x,y)=0$ (no blowing snow, develop steady state) and 0 flux boundary condition. This equation is from the literature, but feels a bit wonky so I'm trying to piece it together.

I would like to solve this via an upwind-scheme -- blowing snow transport moves down wind and should only transport snow to cells downwind.

Further, I would like to solve this on a unstructured triangular mesh.

My hang up (and it's likely a dumb one):

do I discretize this via FVM and then, for each edge, apply an unwind scheme?

Ah the moment I'd like to keep it simple (can move to a better upwind method later), and just find the 'upwind' triangle (via dot-product signs at the edge?) and compute the difference with the current cell. Will that work? If not what is the best way to piece this together?

I appreciate any help, I feel like this is a silly question, but I can't quite wrap my head around the order in which to do this.

Comment: I think you probably want it to be $\partial q/\partial t$ on the left hand side, right?

Comment: Also, the equation $\nabla q = \frac{\partial q}{\partial x} +  \frac{\partial q}{\partial y}$ is definitely not correct. That's not what the gradient is.

Comment: I think the last term in the equation should be $$\nabla\cdot(q \hat{u})$$ right? Regarding the first comment by @WolfgangBangerth, I have the same confusion and this might be partially related to exactly what $q$ is. I first thought it was simply the concentration of snow in the air but your phrase "net blowing snow" makes me unsure.

Comment: dq/dt on LHS: I thought so too (contacted the author), however it is not. I understand the equation to be 'develop a steady state solution' of blowing snow. 
@BillGreene, I think so, yes. $q$ should the positive (deposition) or negative (removal) of snow (kg) in a cell. The $A$ term ends up being a sink over, e.g., vegetation. It assumes a fully developed blowing snow flux, and then scales it with the probability of blowing snow occurring.

Comment: @Chris -- but the equations make no sense just from a dimensional point of view. $\hat u$ has units meters-per-second, the divergence has units one-over-meter, so the rhs has units `[q]`-by-second, but the lhs has units `[q]`. That can't be right.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, Good catch. I dropped a term (F) which is in m. I've edited the post above. I believe the units work correctly. ($kg\cdot m^{-2}\cdot s^{-1}$) = ($kg\cdot m^{-2}\cdot s^{-1}$) - m * 1/m * ($kg\cdot m^{-2}\cdot s^{-1}$)

Comment: But the definition of the gradient is still wrong.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, yes :( I removed it from the OP. I was trying to follow similar to the divergence, as that is what I think it is. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Divergence.html Does the equation/question make more sense now? I appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Yes, it's not a simple advection-reaction equation. Yes, you need upwinding.

Comment: Do I need FVM + upwinding, or just upwinding? I realize this is a naive question, but just trying to figure out my next steps. Thanks again.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Could you comment a bit more on the need for
upwinding in a numerical solution of this equation?
Chris, It is possible to develop a conservative numerical
algorithm with either FDM or FVM. So a primary need for
FVM is based on the complexity of your geometry, e.g.
non-rectangular.

Comment: I think there are so many articles and books on upwinding that I can't do justice to the topic in a comment. The point is that if you have an advection dominated problem, you *need* to stabilize -- and upwinding is one way to do that.